# Why do I never get invited to the developer survey?

Tags: support, notifications, survey-2019

How come that I never get an invitation to the developer survey, but a notification that the results are set?

I have been a member for 6 years, 11 months.

Answer (score 25):

The developer survey puts a prominent banner at the top of the site for several weeks while it is being conducted. The onus is then on users to click  on the banner to take the survey.

Comment: I did receive an email on Jan, 24th informing me the developer survey 2019 was open. I have a rather liberal set of email notifications. Said user might have disabled those email notifications.

Comment: @rene yes and there is the huge banner that's quite hard to miss. That is how I was aware of it and I'm a mod... :/

Comment: We'll put a banner up for you to inform you to look at the banner ;)

Comment: @rene meet me in chat... something something totally unrelated that you will relate to

Comment: @Rene I don't have an email associated with my account, so even though I've never disabled notifications manually, they have no where to arrive to.

Comment: @DavyM ah, yeah, that is a bit hard then. The banners is all there is then for you.

Comment: How does one know that the banner has been put up? Is there a notification that is delivered or can be signed up for? Not everyone visits the site daily, weekly, or even on a regular basis of any kind, but would like to participate...

Comment: @Cypher Exactly. I don't visit the site every day and I don't know if my adblocker shows the banner to me. I want to participate. How should one know about the survey?